# Index not used when Oracle SQL query has large number of selections in the IN(...) statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT statment which a lot of selections in the IN(...) statement.  The column for the IN statment has a nonunique index and is VARCHAR(50).  When the number of elements in the IN statement goes over a certain threshold, the index is not used.

My select is structured like this

```
SELECT T.*, RANK() OVER
 (PARTITION BY KEY_ID ORDER BY OBS_DATE ASC) AS XRANK 
FROM "MY_TABLE" T WHERE KEY_ID IN('A','B','C')
```

But in reality there are a few hundred more elements in the IN statement and they are not called A, B, C.

If I reduce the number of items in my IN statement to 50 the index is used and the query takes 0.003s. 7k rows returned

If I double the items for my IN statment to 100, the index is not used and a full table scan is performed taking 0.4s to return 14k rows.

I'm not sure why the index is not used but I want to see what would happen if it was, so I tried to  experiment I with a hint,

```
SELECT /*+ index(MY_TABLE,MY_INDEX) */ O.*, RANK() OVER ...blah blah
```

But the hint is ignored. When I run the explain plan it is not used and the query is the same speed.

Any advice would be appreciated, especially

1. Why is the index not being used when there is a higher number of elements in the IN statment
2. Why is the hint being ignored.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you convert the IN to a JOIN?

Comment: Yeah, if you have 100s of elements in an IN clause, that is a red flag of the design.

Comment: For your question about why the hint is not used - a reproducible test case would help, along with your exact Oracle version. The optimiser can't ignore hints, but sometimes the nature of the query makes it impossible to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of *selectivity*. If the query is not selective enough, then a full table scan is usually better than multiple index range scans (not unique).

If the number of values is low, the cost based optimizer will consider the cost of multiple index range scans together is still lower than the cost of a full table scan. If you add too many values, then the index range scan will surpass the cost of the full table scan.

Now, the costs are relative, and it depends on how the optimizer is configured (hints), but also depends on the histogram and table stats. Are they up to date?

By the way, you say 7k and 14k rows are selected. What percentage of the table does that represent? If it's too high the engine will go for the heap ignoring the index.

Having said all this, I think this is a really bad design. Instead of sending 100 parameters over the wire, can you produce those values from another table/select instead?

Comment: Thanks for this.  There are 3 million rows.  The data is time series (i.e series identification obsevation values over time). The key is the time series identifier, each key has 'n' observations iterating over time (OBS_DATE).  So the table is very simple, key, observation date, observation value.  The problem is not with the IN(...) on is own, but when used in combination with the rank over partition.  As I am trying to select the last 'n' observations for each key that was selected. So I create a rank and then select where rank < n.

Comment: @Agent96 Maybe you can try adding the index `create index ix1 on "MY_TABLE" (KEY_ID, OBS_DATE);`. It's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks - the index made no improvement unfortunately.